# Undefined index error on going to shopping cart page in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart, index

After adding Product to cart and clicking on shopping cart link. I am getting this error
Undefined index: 8039,8219 in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php on line 316

See https://nimb.ws/0GCiSF
I am using MAgento 2.3.3
Link to reproduce url : https://wholesale-e92rduand89atx1x.mojostratus.io/v2-zorb-4d-cotton-dimple-pul-silver.html

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: May you try to print the collection to string. Cart/Collection.php from here this full address get from log. print the collection then die; the code to see what is there in collection. Seems like that product id is not present in product database table.

Comment: Where can i check the product ids in database? Which table?